# Illustrator moves anything I select

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Whenever I select an object by clicking on it in Illustrator CS6, the second I move my mouse it moves the object. Is there a way around this? I just need to select an object and then change it's color or font but as soon as I move my mouse, the object is moved 3-4 pixels.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out based on this post: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/758287.

I had Rightzoom running in the background and once I turned it off, all was well. I hope this helps anyone else and thanks for your help @tehMacDawg.

Whew!

Comment: Rightzoom was the culprit for me too. Added it to the exceptions list and all is well in Illustrator land.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects move only a few pixels, might this be related to the notorious **Align to Pixel Grid** option? When creating a new Illustrator document for screen media, there is this option in the 'New' dialog box that is activated by default. (It helps avoiding blurry lines in the artwork when creating graphics for screens...) If you've been creating a new document, do this again and uncheck that option. Otherwise, it's possible to activate/deactivate this automatic re-alignment for each object using the **Transform panel** (you need to expand the options of the Transform panel via the drop-down menu in the upper right corner.)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with the mouse, not Illustrator. There is absolutely no "sticky click" option anywhere in Illustrator

:)